# Bluestacks Application - Failed to Load Channels. Unable to connect to the Internet

Tags: macos, android, bluestacks

I have installed the [Bluestacks 2](http://www.bluestacks.com) application on Mac OS X (El Capitan). The application is installed successfully.

When I launch the application, I get this weird error

> "Failed to load channels. Unable to connect to the Internet".

I tried searching on Internet but no success. Also, if I browse internet through Bluestacks browser, I could connect to internet.

I have installed Bluestacks 2 Application previously and it used to work properly. Screenshots are attached for reference.

Any Solution?

I use Bluestack Version - 0.9.30 (423902).

[image: Bluestacks Error Screen]

[image: Bluestack Browsing Internet]

Comment: How did you open the Bluestacks browser?  I can't even do that

Comment: @Polyergic - Click the "All Apps" button on the home screen. I also can browse the internet, but no channels. Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Still no solution to channel issue, but you can navigate to the google play store through the browser -> when prompted open the play store app -> link your google account -> then install apps. Which is good enough for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using an app that connects you to a Vpn such as [This Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.psiphon3&hl=en)

Ive read a lot of issues of the VPN fixing the issue so let me know if it does.

Just install it and wait a few minutes and see if it clears up.

If it works click [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-vpn-apps-577594/) for another list of vpns if you do not like the one listed above.

It seems this error occurs when something within bluestacks is unable to communicate through the internet you are using. The VPN allows the app to think its using another network since you are actually using the vpn within Bluestacks itself.

Hope this helps.